# Typescript Generics: return type of subinstance

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```js
    interface A{
      propertyA: SubProperty<string>;
      propertyB: SubProperty<number>;
      propertyD: number;
    }
    type supported = string | number;
    class SubProperty<T extends supported>{
     data:T
    }
    
    
    type PropertyOfValue<T, V> = {
      [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V
        ? K
        : never
    }[keyof T];
    
    type B = PropertyOfValue<A, SubProperty<supported>>;
    
    class ParentClass{
    constructor(protected a:A, protected b:B){}
    
    getSubPropertyType(){
    //  I would like that function to return the type of this.a[this.b].data
return typeof this.a[this.b].data;
    }
    }
    
    
    
    
    const a:A = {
      propertyA: new SubProperty<string>(),
      propertyB: new SubProperty<number>(),
      propertyD: 1
    }
    
    
    class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    constructor(){
    super(a, 'propertyA');
    console.log(this.getSubPropertyType())
    }
    }
    
    var test = new ChildClass();
    console.log(test.getSubPropertyType())
```

How can I tell typescript compiler that `test.getSubPropertyType()` can be only a string or undefined?
How can I explicit tell him that it cannot be other type?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/rw224w) what you are looking for? If not, could you please add some text or code that details exactly what you are trying to do?  Maybe show some example of code that has an error where you expect no error?  Good luck!

Comment: That was exactly what I'm looking for. But Is there a way to have the same behavior without modify the ParentClass signature? I mean, without make it generic? I would like to change only the `getSubPropertyType` function.

Comment: @jcalz There is 2 things that bothers me with your solution.
1- I will have to modify all `ChildClass` usages.
2 - I have no intellisence in the generic type for `class ParentClass<BB extends B>`

Comment: You will have to modify usages, yes.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/qNB8kW) instead, if you want, using [polymorphic `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) instead of generics.  But then you will still have to change child classes to explicitly narrow the type of `b`, and furthermore `b` has to be public.  I'm wondering how you expect the compiler to know that `b` is narrower without telling it?  I'm happy to write up an answer but I'm still not sure if it meets your needs, or if you will just have follow-up issues.

Comment: I thank you very much. I expect the compiler to know the type because I s `propertyA` in parent. It cannot work that way?

Comment: Do you know why i don't have intellicense in generic type of the class (using you're first answer)

Comment: It does not work that way; you have defined `ParentClass` so that its `b` property is the union `"propertyA" | "propertyB"`.  Just because you *initialize* `ChildClass`'s `b` property to `"propertyA"` it does not mean that the compiler thinks that it will always be that specific value.  Such control-flow analysis based narrowings do not persist across function boundaries.  The compiler sees `b` as `"propertyA" | "propertyB"`, unless you explicitly tell it that it won't change... either with generics or with narrowing property declarations.

Comment: You have mentioned that you "lose intellisense" multiple times but this is where I need a [mcve] that shows me what you're talking about. *Where* do you lose it?  And is this really pertinent to the question?  Or rather, is it relevant to whether or not this general approach constitutes an answer?